# How to filter keys in MIDP TextField?

Tags: java, java-me, textfield, midp

I have a `TextField.PhoneNumber` but I would like to filter out "+" character. In other words, I need a new constraint for TextField. Is there a way to define a new constraint with TextField?

How about preventing keys from cycling on a mobile phone within a midp?

Comment: '+' is a standard prefix for country codes.  Why do you want to filter it out?

Comment: My client has a special requirement. Key cycling is slowing down the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not what you really want.
But, MIDP does not support change constraint rule as you want. So, I suggest HACK for your purpose.

How about use ItemStateListener to check if text field contains string which you want to filter out and if this string is exist, change text field forcefully.

The code could be looks like below:

```
// set item state listener
form.setItemStateListener(this);

// check if text field contains invalid string
// then replace it
public void itemStateChanged(Item item) {
    if (item == getTextField()) {
        TextField t = (TextField)item;
        String s = t.getString();
        // + is invalid string
        int pos = s.indexOf("+");
        if (pos != -1) {
            t.setString(s.substring(0, pos) + s.substring(pos + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty cool. Your solution works. Thanks.
However, I have to extend form on a separate class to get it working. Now it's doesn't play well with the rest of the code. Will report back here soon.